# chef loop and notifies

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

To place two certificates in the box and then add them to a wallet I used the below code.

```
RDS_CA_CERTS = %w[ cert1.cer cert2.cer]
RDS_CA_CERTS.each do |rds_ca_cert|
  cookbook_file "/oracle_home/ssl_wallet/#{rds_ca_cert}" do
    source "certs/#{rds_ca_cert}"
    owner 'oracle'
    group 'dba'
    mode '0644'
    action :create
    notifies :run, 'execute[import_rds_cert]', :immediately
  end

  execute 'import_rds_cert' do
    command "orapki wallet add -wallet /oracle_home/ssl_wallet -trusted_cert -cert /oracle_home/ssl_wallet/#{rds_ca_cert} -auto_login_only"
    user 'oracle'
    group 'dba'
    umask '0025'
    action :nothing
  end
end
```

I was expecting the above code will bring in one file cert1.cer and trigger the execute for the same. Then it will bring in cert2.cer and with trigger execute.
This way only when file is added the execute will be triggered(gate for execute resoure)

But in TK observed behaviour is bit strange to me. It bring in cert1.cer file and then when it triggers execute it fails saying cert2.cer is not there. 
That can happen only if the loop has moved to next file before the execute was triggered.

Can you please explain the behavior ?
What would be better alternative approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code generates 2 cookbook_file resources and 2 execute resources. Unfortunately your execute resources have the same name and eventually merged into 1 resource by Chef with the latter resource's command overwriting the previous one. So your `cookbook_file "/oracle_home/ssl_wallet/cert1.cer"` resource triggers `execute 'import_rds_cert'` resource with `command "orapki wallet add -wallet /oracle_home/ssl_wallet -trusted_cert -cert /oracle_home/ssl_wallet/cert2.cer -auto_login_only"`.

To solve your problem change the name of the execute resource, so that it is depending on `rds_ca_cert` variable. This way Chef will generate 2 different execute resources too.

```
cookbook_file "/oracle_home/ssl_wallet/#{rds_ca_cert}" do
  [...]
  notifies :run, "execute[import_rds_cert_#{rds_ca_cert}]", :immediately
end

execute "import_rds_cert_#{rds_ca_cert}" do
  [...]
end
```